# Extract number outside the parentheses in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the problem with this string:

```
'4.0718393*nt(placement5,placement6)+4.021677*nt(placement4)'
```

and want have this result:

```
[4.0718393, 4.021677]
```

Simply said, I want to extract the numbers outside the parentheses in python. I found this regex pattern which will extract every number in a string and is not helping me get further.

```
re.findall("[-+]?\d+[\.]?\d*[eE]?[-+]?\d*", string)
```

Comment: Is it sure that there are no nested parentheses?

Comment: Are those numbers always on the same position with same number of different caracters between them?

Comment: Yes, I am sure there are no nested parentheses, because I have done some pre-works.

Comment: No, the numbers have different number of characters between them. Jobo Fernandez has solved my problem, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

text = '4.0718393*nt(placement5,placement6)+4.021677*nt(placement4)'
matches = re.findall(r"\d+\.\d+", text)
```

Comment: Yes, it answers my problem! Thank you!

Comment: @Zyy just FYI, that catches all decimal-valued texts anywhere in text. So if you have like ```(placement6.0)```, it catches that 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Number can be at the start, at the end of the string. Or in two cases in the middle of the string. One case surrounded by brackets, the other not surrounded by brackets. To avoid in this case numbers in brackets in this particular case one may use this regex in re.findall.

```
[)][^(]*(\d+\.\d+)[^)]*[(]

s = '4.0718393*nt(placement5,2739.14*placement6,44.555)+4.021677*nt(placement4.0),777.311'
    
    list(filter(None,(chain(*re.findall(r',(\d+\.\d+)$|^(\d+\.\d+)|[)][^(]*(\d+\.\d+)[^)]*[(]',s)))))
    
    ['4.0718393', '4.021677', '777.311']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to extract the decimal number use this regex expression
\d+(.\d+)+

```
import re

text = '4.0718393*nt(placement5,placement6)+4.021677*nt(placement4)'
matches = re.findall(r"\d+(\.\d+)+", text)
```